# Better / More pythonic way to process the results of a function with multiple return values

Tags: python, function, python-2.7

The code below works, but looks very ugly. I'm looking for a more pythonic way to write the same thing.

The goal:
React on a result of a function that returns multiple values.

Example function

```
def myfilterfunc(mystr):
   if 'la' in mystr:
       return True, mystr
   return False, None
```

This returns True and a string (if the string cointains "la"), or False and nothing.

In a second function, I'm passing *myfilterfunc* as an optional parameter

```
def mymainfunc(mystr,filterfunc=None):
```

This function fills a returnlist.
If no function is given, the result is not filtered and added as is.
If a filter function is given, if the filter function returns
True, a returned string is added. (This is just an example that would
easily work with one return value, but I'm trying to get the systax
right for a more complicated setup)

```
if filterfunc:
    tmp_status,tmp_string = filterfunc(mystr[startpos:nextitem])
    if tmp_status:
        returnlist.append(tmp_string)
    else:
        returnlist.append(mystr[startpos:nextitem])
```

Any idea how I can write this without using temporary variables to store the return values of the function?

Full "working" test code below

```
def string2list(mystr,splitlist,filterfunc=None):
    returnlist = []
    startpos = 0
    nextitem = -1
    matched = True
    while matched:
        matched = False
        for sub in splitlist:
            if startpos == 0:
                tmpi = mystr.find(sub)
            else:    
                tmpi = mystr.find(sub,startpos + 1)
            if (tmpi > 0) and ((nextitem < 0) or (nextitem > tmpi)):
                nextitem = tmpi
                matched = True
        if filterfunc:
            tmp_status,tmp_string = filterfunc(mystr[startpos:nextitem])
            if tmp_status:
                returnlist.append(tmp_string)
        else:
            returnlist.append(mystr[startpos:nextitem])
        startpos = nextitem 
        nextitem = -1
    return returnlist

def myfilterfunc(mystr):
    if 'la' in mystr:
        return True,mystr
    return False,''    


splitlist = ['li','la']
mytext = '''
li1
li2
li3
fg4
fg5
fg6
la7
la
la
tz
tz
tzt
tz
end
'''



print string2list(mytext,splitlist)
print
print string2list(mytext,splitlist,myfilterfunc)
```

Comment: Why don't you just return the string or `None`?

Comment: This is a very simple programming example in which I try to find out how to handle two return values, not the very complex thing I will do later...

Comment: Then please give a more representative example, see [mcve].

Comment: I added the full code of my example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is going to happen often you can factor out the uglyness:

```
def filtered(f, x):
    if f:
        status, result = f(x)
        return result if status else x
    else:
        return x
```

used like

```
returnlist.append(filtered(filterfunc, mystr[startpos:nextitem]))
```

so that if you have many similar optional filters the code remains readable. This works because in Python functions/closures are first class citizens and you can pass them around like other values.

But then if the logic is about always adding (either the filtered or the unfiltered) why not just write the filter to return the input instead of `(False, "")` in case of failure?

That would make the code simpler to understand...

```
returnlist.append(filterfunc(mystr[startpos:nextitem]))
```

Comment: Because I wrote this as an example of a two value return to learn the python syntax (coming from a Pascal like language) and I'm still trying to find the right ways to do things. Also, when I return one value (string or None) and use `returnlist.append(filterfunc(mystr[startpos:nextitem]))` and do not pass the optional *filterfunc* to the main function, the code crashes with *NoneType not callable*

Comment: one more comment, I am not always adding. If the *filterfunc* returns False (or None) I am not adding. I'm adding, if the *filterfunc* returns something or no *filterfunc* was given.

Comment: I solved the optional *filterfunc* problem with `if filterfunc is None: filterfunc = lambda x:x`, then the one line append works...

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two better approaches to your problem that don't involve using two return values.

The first is to simply return a Boolean value and not a string at all. This works if your filter is always going to return the string it was passed unmodified if it returns a string at all (e.g. if the first value is `True`). This approach will let you avoid using temporary values at all:

```
if filterfunc:
    if filterfunc(mystr[startpos:nextitem]):
        returnlist.append(mystr[startpos:nextitem])
```

(Note, I'd suggest renaming `filterfunc` to `predicate` if you go this route.)

The other option will work if some `filterfunc` might return a different second value than it was passed under some situations, but never the 2-tuple `True, None`. In this approach you simply use the single value as both the signal and the payload. If it's `None`, you ignore it. If it's anything else, you use it. This does require a temporary variable, but only one (and it's a lot less ugly).

```
if filterfunc:
    result = filterfunc(mystr[startpos:nextitem])
    if result is not None:
        returnlist.append(result)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is example code, I'm trying to see how I can play with an optional function that returns more than one value. My main aim is to see if this can be written in a way that works well in Python and avoids temporary variables...